# i want to convert sample JSON data into nested JSON using specific key-value in python

Tags: python, json

I have below sample data in JSON format :

`project_cost_details` is my database result set after querying.

```
{
    "1": {
        "amount": 0,
        "breakdown": [
            {
                "amount": 169857,
                "id": 4,
                "name": "SampleData",
                "parent_id": "1"
            }
          ],
         "id": 1,
        "name": "ABC PR"
    }
}
```

Here is full json : https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2ce7ab19af6f420397b07b939674f49c

Expected output :https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=56a47e6f8e424fe8ac58c5e0732168d7

I have this sample JSON which i created using loops in code. But i am stuck at how to convert this to expected JSON format. I am getting sequential changes, need to convert to tree like or nested JSON format.

Trying in Python :

```py
project_cost = {}
        for cost in project_cost_details:
            if cost.get('Parent_Cost_Type_ID'):
                project_id = str(cost.get('Project_ID'))
                parent_cost_type_id = str(cost.get('Parent_Cost_Type_ID'))
                if project_id not in project_cost:
                    project_cost[project_id] = {}
                if "breakdown" not in project_cost[project_id]:
                    project_cost[project_id]["breakdown"] = []
                if 'amount' not in project_cost[project_id]:
                    project_cost[project_id]['amount'] = 0
                project_cost[project_id]['name'] = cost.get('Title')
                project_cost[project_id]['id'] = cost.get('Project_ID')
                if parent_cost_type_id == cost.get('Cost_Type_ID'):
                    project_cost[project_id]['amount'] += int(cost.get('Amount'))
                #if parent_cost_type_id is None:

                project_cost[project_id]["breakdown"].append(
                    {
                        'amount': int(cost.get('Amount')),
                        'name': cost.get('Name'),
                        'parent_id': parent_cost_type_id,
                        'id' : cost.get('Cost_Type_ID')
                    }
                )
```

from this i am getting sample JSON. It will be good if get in this code only desired format.

Also tried this solution mention here : https://adiyatmubarak.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/group-list-of-dictionary-data-by-particular-key-in-python/

Comment: What are the keys `Parent_Cost_Type_ID`, `Project_ID`, `Parent_Cost_Type_ID` in your sample code? These keys are not in your sample input/output json files.

Comment: this is coming from result after running query. You can help me changes my sample JSON to expected JSON. Python i am getting sample JSON which i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got approach to convert sample JSON to expected JSON :

```py
data = [
 { "name" : "ABC", "parent":"DEF",  },
 { "name" : "DEF", "parent":"null" },
 { "name" : "new_name", "parent":"ABC" },
 { "name" : "new_name2", "parent":"ABC" },
 { "name" : "Foo", "parent":"DEF"},
 { "name" : "Bar", "parent":"null"},
  { "name" : "Chandani", "parent":"new_name", "relation": "rel", "depth": 3 },
  { "name" : "Chandani333", "parent":"new_name", "relation": "rel", "depth": 3 }
]

result = {x.get("name"):x for x in data}
#print(result)
tree = [];
for a in data:
    #print(a)
    if a.get("parent") in result:
        parent = result[a.get("parent")]
    else:
        parent = "" 
    if parent:
        if "children" not in parent:
            parent["children"] = []
        parent["children"].append(a)

    else:
        tree.append(a)
```

**Reference help** : http://jsfiddle.net/9FqKS/  this is a JavaScript solution i converted to Python

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you want to get a list of values from a dictionary.

`result = [value for key, value in project_cost_details.items()]`

Comment: Check the `json` of the expected output.

Comment: doesn't the expected output look like an array of dictionaries?