# Javascript array json converting to parent child json object

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
 var rawData1 = {
  root: [
    "children": [
      {
        "country": "Japan",
        "children": [
          {
            "C1": "Japan 225343-17510-ADV HIV"
          },
          {
            "C2": "Japan 245123-142567"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "country": "EU",
        "children": [
          {
            "C1": "345112-765431-HID
          },
          {
            "C2": "22535"
          },
          {
            "C3": "EU 22535"
          },
          {
            "C4": "EU 8988-90"
          },
          {
            "C5": "EU 8988-90"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "country": "Canada",
        "children": [
          {
            "C1": "Canada 345112-765431-HID"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "country": "Switzerland",
        "children": [
          {
            "C1": "Switzerland 345112-765431-HID"
          }, {
            "C2": "Switzerland 22535"
          }, {
            "C3": "Switzerland 8988-90"
          }, {
            "C4": "Switzerland 8988-90"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "country": "US",
        "children": [
          {
            "C1": "US 345112-765431-HID",
          }, {
            "C2": "US 22535"
          }, {
            "C3": "US 46489"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

I want to convert the rawData array to rawData1 array.

rawData1 is the parent-child in form of Json.

The parent and Child are decided based on key only

( NOt key-value only key Eg: if key is country then it is parent or else it is child) if key is C1 or C2 etc

then it is child array with each separate object of key-value only you can see the code for more detail

---

Thank you ver much you code worked very well

Now i want one more Child like in

{

root:{

“country” : "Japan"

children:[

```
            {"C1":"879"}

            {"C2":"jk"}

            children:[

                            {"C3":"Code","C4":"Codei"}, //for C3 and C4 create nested children to above children

                            {"C5":"Code","C6":"Codei"} // if data is present C5 andC6



                            ]
```

]

}

This is want i want your variable call childrenArray inside this i want one more array called ChildrenSubArray

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072709/i-want-to-convert-sample-json-data-into-nested-json-using-specific-key-value-in try this.

Comment: Thats python? @aviboy2006

Comment: Try logic in java script same.

Comment: Why did you remove half your code...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using a for in loop within a map function:

```js
var rawData = {
    results: [{
      "country": "Japan",
      "C1": "Japan 225343-17510-ADV HIV",
      "C2": "Japan 245123-142567"
  
    }, {
      "country": "EU",
      "C1": "345112-765431-HID",
      "C2": "22535",
      "C3": "EU 22535",
      "C4": "EU 8988-90",
      "C5": "EU 8988-90"
    }, {
      "country": "Canada",
      "C1": "Canada 345112-765431-HID",
    }, {
      "country": "Switzerland",
      "C1": "Switzerland 345112-765431-HID",
      "C2": "Switzerland 22535",
      "C3": "Switzerland 8988-90",
      "C4": "Switzerland 8988-90"
    }, {
      "country": "US",
      "C1": "US 345112-765431-HID",
      "C2": "US 22535",
      "C3": "US 46489"
    }]
  };

var results = rawData.results;

children = results.map(function(x) {
    var childrenArray = [];
    for(const child in x) {
        if(child != "country") {
            childrenArray.push({
                [child]: x[child]
            })
        }
    }

    return {
        "country": x.country,
        "children": childrenArray
    }
})

var rawData1 = {
    root: [{
        "children": children
    }]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(rawData1, null, 4));
```

Comment: I want one children like children>children>diamond like inside children Array I want one more array name diamond and also some more values with country key in first children.

Comment: My result is exactly like what you were asking for in your question. No clue what you are talking about

Comment: Hi Nicolas Siegmundt you can see I updated the question

Comment: hi Nicolas please give this solution. i need one child under childrenArray. it's appreciating what you did