# Convert list of dictionaries into list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, data-structures

I tried and saw multiple solutions for the above question but could not find a solution that suits my case.
I have following list of dictionaries.

```
input_list = [
                {'k0':'v0','level':0,'row':0},
                {'k1':'v1','level':1,'row':1},
                {'k2':'v2','level':2,'row':2},
                {'k3':'v3','level':2,'row':3},
                {'k4':'v4','level':1,'row':4},
                {'k5':'v5','level':2,'row':5},
                {'k6':'v6','level':1,'row':6},
                {'k7':'v7','level':0,'row':7},
                {'k8':'v8','level':1,'row':8},
                {'k9':'v9','level':2,'row':9},
            ]
```

and I need to convert this list to list of nested dictionaries in the following way

```
[
  {'k0':'v0',
   'level':0,
   'child':[
          {'k1':'v1','level':1,'child':[{'k2':'v2','level':2}, 
                                        {'k3':'v3','level':2}]},
          {'k4':'v4','level':1,'child':[{'k5':'v5','level':2}]},
          {'k6':'v6','level':1}
         ]},

  {'k7':'v7',
   'level':0,
   'child':[{'k8':'v8','level':1,'child':[{'k9':'v9','level':2}]}]}
]
```

Solutions which I tried are as follow

```
levels = dict()
for n in input_list:
    levels.setdefault(n['level'], []).append(n)
```

this gives me dictionaries with levels separated but I couldn't move past this code for my desired solution

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: *"could not find a solution"* - did you try to *make* a solution?

Comment: We cannot help you if we dont know the rule you want to use in nasting. Why do you need to group in that way? Is there special consideration you take for a group of objects to be children of other children?

Comment: @kim rules for the problem are level 0 dictionary should be parent one and all subsequent levels must be a child of the parent in a sequence of the list i.e. from 0 to ahead (row value)

Comment: have you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072709/i-want-to-convert-sample-json-data-into-nested-json-using-specific-key-value-in

Comment: I suggest you start by writing **in words** the rules that you use to decide what to do with each dict in the input list.

Comment: a few comments: invalid syntax, list_of_dictionaries is not defined, you mask the dict class before trying to use the dict class, the desired output shouldn't need "level" attributes, the "row" doesn't seem to have any purpose

Comment: Being curious: Whats the reason that makes u need that super-complex nested dictionary structure ?

Comment: @KennyOstrom row is for illustration purpose only & edited question for _invalid syntax_ issue

Comment: you need to put quotes around a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
data = [{'k0': 'v0', 'level': 0, 'row': 0}, {'k1': 'v1', 'level': 1, 'row': 1}, {'k2': 'v2', 'level': 2, 'row': 2}, {'k3': 'v3', 'level': 2, 'row': 3}, {'k4': 'v4', 'level': 1, 'row': 4}, {'k5': 'v5', 'level': 2, 'row': 5}, {'k6': 'v6', 'level': 1, 'row': 6}, {'k7': 'v7', 'level': 0, 'row': 7}, {'k8': 'v8', 'level': 1, 'row': 8}, {'k9': 'v9', 'level': 2, 'row': 9}]
_d = [{a:b for a, b in i.items() if a not in {'row'}} for i in data]

def get_results(d, l = 0):
  r, p = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in gb(d, key=lambda x:x['level'] == l)], []
  for a, b in r:
     if a:
        p.extend(b)
     else:      
        p[-1]['child'] = get_results(b, l+1)
  return p
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(get_results(_d), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "k0": "v0",
    "level": 0,
    "child": [
        {
            "k1": "v1",
            "level": 1,
            "child": [
                {
                    "k2": "v2",
                    "level": 2
                },
                {
                    "k3": "v3",
                    "level": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "k4": "v4",
            "level": 1,
            "child": [
                {
                    "k5": "v5",
                    "level": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "k6": "v6",
            "level": 1
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "k7": "v7",
    "level": 0,
    "child": [
        {
            "k8": "v8",
            "level": 1,
            "child": [
                {
                    "k9": "v9",
                    "level": 2
                }
            ]
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks for answering tho it fails to capture all values of level 2

Comment: @KetanPujare It does, the code originally condensed multiple children into a single `dict` in case there was a set of children that had its own sublevel. However, please see my recent edit, as I added a workaround that matches your desired output.

Answer (score 3):

```
# This stores last dicts seen by their levels
dict_by_levels = [None] * len(input_list)

# To be returned; begins with the first "root"
output_list = [input_list[0]]

for prev_dict, cur_dict in zip(input_list, input_list[1:]):
    # Get previous and current level, and store them in levels dict
    prev_level, cur_level = prev_dict["level"], cur_dict["level"]
    dict_by_levels[prev_level] = prev_dict
    dict_by_levels[cur_level] = cur_dict

    # If we are currently in a deeper level, append to previous dict's child
    if cur_level > prev_level:
        prev_dict.setdefault("child", []).append(cur_dict) 

    # If we are currently in a shallower or equal level *and* the current level is not 0,
    # then get the last one-level-before dict seen so far, and append to it
    elif cur_level <= prev_level and cur_level != 0:
        dict_by_levels[cur_level-1].setdefault("child", []).append(cur_dict)

    # This else is equivalent to "if cur_level == 0" i.e. a "root" dict
    else:
        output_list.append(cur_dict)
```

I keep track of two level for each turn of the loop i.e. previous and current dicts. I also make `dict_by_levels` which is a list of dicts by level; index 0, 1, 2.. will have the last dictionary seen by that level, if any. This helps in the case where we go a shallower or equal level (e.g. from 2 to 2).

If the current level is higher than previous level (e.g. 1 > 0), then we simply append to children of current dict.

If the current level is less than equal to the previous level, this means that we should be appending to the children of last seen dict with level `current level - 1` (`dict_by_levels` helps here). Of course, if current level is `0`, we don't do this - we have a new root.

And that root case is handled in `else` clause via appending to the output list to be returned.